# Timeout in tests when running pintos

Tags: pintos

I am just getting started with the pintos projects, working from my home computer that is running ubuntu 14.04 x64 system.

I'm able to compile the project from the `src/threads/` directory, and the initial test `pintos run alarm-multiple` seems to work okay (notice that it runs qemu by default):

```
zay@ubuntu:~/Documents/pintos/src/threads/build$ pintos run alarm-multiple
Prototype mismatch: sub main::SIGVTALRM () vs none at /home/zay/Documents/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 935.
Constant subroutine SIGVTALRM redefined at /home/zay/Documents/pintos/src/utils/pintos line 927.
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive cache=writeback,file=/tmp/YS3E7FICwo.dsk -m 4 -net none -serial stdio
PiLo hda1
Loading..........
Kernel command line: run alarm-multiple
Pintos booting with 4,088 kB RAM...
382 pages available in kernel pool.
382 pages available in user pool.
Calibrating timer...  286,310,400 loops/s.
Boot complete.
Executing 'alarm-multiple':
(alarm-multiple) begin
(alarm-multiple) Creating 5 threads to sleep 7 times each.
(alarm-multiple) Thread 0 sleeps 10 ticks each time,
(alarm-multiple) thread 1 sleeps 20 ticks each time, and so on.
(alarm-multiple) If successful, product of iteration count and
(alarm-multiple) sleep duration will appear in nondescending order.
(alarm-multiple) thread 0: duration=10, iteration=1, product=10
(alarm-multiple) thread 0: duration=10, iteration=2, product=20
```

However, when I run `make check` under `src/threads/build`, all tests get a timeout fault:

```
zay@ubuntu:~/Documents/pintos/src/threads/build$ make check
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-multiple < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-multiple.errors > tests/threads/alarm-multiple.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-multiple.ck tests/threads/alarm-multiple tests/threads/alarm-multiple.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-multiple
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.20, 0.45, 0.26
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-simultaneous < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.errors > tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.ck tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.18, 0.40, 0.25
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu  -- -q  run alarm-priority < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-priority.errors > tests/threads/alarm-priority.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-priority.ck tests/threads/alarm-priority tests/threads/alarm-priority.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-priority
run: TIMEOUT after 61 seconds of wall-clock time - load average: 0.10, 0.34, 0.2
```

What changes should I make to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, QEMU no longer supports the power off sequence on the port `0x8900`. Here is a fix that made it work for me (found in [chaOs](https://github.com/Kijewski/chaOS/blob/master/core/shutdown.c)): in the file `devices/shutdown.c` patch `shutdown_power_off` as follows:

```
void
shutdown_power_off (void)
{
  // ...
  printf ("Powering off...\n");
  serial_flush ();
  outw (0xB004, 0x2000);  // <-- Add this line
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This line has been included in the newer versions from what I can see; but I am still getting the same error, at times

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **qemu** for pintos.
You need to add one line of code in `devices/shutdown.c`.

Insert the line
`outw( 0x604, 0x0 | 0x2000 );` after `printf (“Powering off…\n”); serial_flush ();` as shown below:

```
 /* This is a special power-off sequence supported by Bochs and
 QEMU, but not by physical hardware. */
 for (p = s; *p != '  printf ("Powering off...\n");
  serial_flush ();

//add the following line
outw( 0x604, 0x0 | 0x2000 );
```

Follow [this guide](https://arpith.xyz/2016/01/getting-started-with-pintos/) to find out more